Feasibility of self-modifying prompts for enhanced performance in Generative AI
I'm exploring the idea of self-modifying prompts within generative AI models, where the prompt itself evolves based on the output it generates, aiming to improve performance iteratively.
The concept is inspired by feedback loops, where each iteration refines the input to achieve better results. Specifically, I'm considering a system where the prompt dynamically adjusts based on the AI's output, possibly incorporating reinforcement learning or other optimization techniques.
Questions:

Is this concept theoretically feasible within the current capabilities of generative AI models like GPT or others?
What are the potential challenges or limitations in implementing such a self-modifying prompt system?
Are there existing approaches or research that explore similar ideas, such as adaptive prompts or feedback-based modifications?
What would be the best starting point or methodology for experimenting with this concept?

I'm particularly interested in the technical feasibility and any existing methodologies that could support such an approach. Insights or references to relevant literature would be highly appreciated.

The feasibility of self-modifying prompts for enhanced performance in Generative AI has been explored e.g. in
https://arxiv.org/abs/2402.02101:

LLM-based Automatic Prompt Optimization, which typically utilizes LLMs as Prompt Optimizers to self-reflect and refine prompts, has shown promising performance in recent studies. Despite the success, the underlying mechanism of this approach remains unexplored, and the true effectiveness of LLMs as Prompt Optimizers requires further validation. In this work, we conducted a comprehensive study to uncover the actual mechanism of LLM-based Prompt Optimization. Our findings reveal that the LLM optimizers struggle to identify the true causes of errors during reflection, tending to be biased by their own prior knowledge rather than genuinely reflecting on the errors. Furthermore, even when the reflection is semantically valid, the LLM optimizers often fail to generate appropriate prompts for the target models with a single prompt refinement step, partly due to the unpredictable behaviors of the target models. Based on the observations, we introduce a new "Automatic Behavior Optimization" paradigm, which directly optimizes the target model's behavior in a more controllable manner. We hope our study can inspire new directions for automatic prompt optimization development.

